# iRedMail + Apache + MySQL + Ubuntu 20

Tags: apache2, mysql, mail, mail-server

I have VSP with Ubuntu 20. There is already installed Apache and Mysql. Is it possible to install and run iRedMail server on this device? I started with Mail-in-a-box mail server but it requires fresh clean server with Ubuntu 18. So I am not sure if it will work correctly with other services. Thank you for any help.

Comment: If they support Ubuntu 18.04 but not 20.04, that may mean they require Python 2. It is more important than being a fresh install. You may want to check that. Also I would advise Christoph Haas's ISPMail, you can check it from: https://workaround.org/ispmail. The tutorial prepared for Debian but compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 (I verify that). It is not so easy but there are tools for automatic install for ISPMail, you can check one at https://www.karasite.xyz.

Comment: There is no such versions as 18 or 20 please clarify the version.

Comment: I mean LTS versions 20 and 18. Its common use case to install services based on LTS version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @karasite.xyz It seems iRedMail also requires clean OS as they write on their site: "...which means you can not have other network services running on the server BEFORE iRedMail installation."

Comment: It looks like that you may have problems with iRedMail, you can try and see, but it might be very difficult to revert. You may want to test it on a virtual server before.

Comment: I am going to buy separate VPS for it https://contabo.com/en/vps/vps-s-ssd/ I had one VPS on Azure which costs about 4.5e/month and resources was very poor. So I leave Azure and buy new one from Contabo which is also on another level.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Both of those projects require fresh install of the specified Ubuntu version and both use nginx.